# Disable Tier Price in Backend Magento

Tags: magento, backend

Does anyone know a way not to display the tier price in the backend of Magento @product page?

Due to the large list of Tier prices, loading a product takes a long time in the backbend.

When I try to remove the attribute from the Management attributes sets default, I get a message and cannot remove it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Thanks  Enigmativity I have add it on  magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to file `frontend/default/yourtheme/tempalte/catalog/product/view.phtml`
2. Find `echo $this->getTierPriceHtml()`
3. comment above mentioned line

Comment: Please, format your code using `{}` button when your post it!